# How to create dummy for levels above a certain threshold of a column with high cardinality?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, multiple-columns, categorical-data, dummy-variable

so i have this column with high cardinality :

```
   Df['Education_Degree'].value_counts():

   Masters Degree in Mathematics                      5550
   Bachelors Degree in Physics                        4420
   Bacherlors Degree                                  3210
   Masters Degree in Mechanics                        2540
   Masters Degree                                     1200
   Masters Degree in Economics                        995
   .
   .
   .

   Name: Education_Degree, Length: 356, dtype: int64
```

And What I want to do is to create dummy columns but only for levels above 995 , Any Suggestion Would Be Much Appreciated , Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case

```
s=Df['Education_Degree'].value_counts()
sdumm=pd.get_dummies(Df.loc[Df['Education_Degree'].isin(s.index[s>=995]),'Education_Degree'])
```

Then just `concat`

```
yourdf=pd.concat([Df,sdumm.reindex(Df.index).fillna(0)],axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Value counts provides enough information to do that.

```
c=Df['Education_Degree'].value_counts()
```

This returns [Series](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.html) object. And we can use that to create dummies. Or we can use different way to get value counts:

```
c=Df.groupby('Education_Degree', sort=False)['Education_Degree'].count().sort_values(ascending=False)
```

The result will be the same.

Once we have the series object we can create dummies. But there is another solution. Instead geting the columns we would like to keep:

```
c=c[c>995]
```

We can get the columns we don't like to keep.

```
c=c[c<=995]
c_remove = c.index.tolist() # list of columns not to keep
```

This way we don't even call `get_dummies()`, all we do use this:

```
for i in range(0, len(Df)):
    c=Df.loc[i,'Education_Degree']
    Df.loc[i, c]=1
```

And then finally we would remove the columns:

```
Df.drop(c_remove, axis=1)
```